# Understanding python tuple to list performance optimization

Tags: python, list, tuples

I have a tuple, say, atup = (1,3,4,5,6,6,7,78,8) and produced dynamically by list of tuples when iterated (generator yield). Each tuple needs to get converted to list so each elements of tuple can be transformed further and used in a method. While doing this, I was surprised to learn that just doing list(atup) is much faster than using list comprehension like this [i for i in atup]. Here is what I did:

Performance Test 1:

```
timeit.timeit('list((1,3,4,5,6,6,7,78,8))', number=100000)
0.02268475245609025
```

Performance Test 2:

```
timeit.timeit('[i for i in (1,3,4,5,6,6,7,78,8)]', number=100000)
0.05304025196801376
```

Can you please explain this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The list comprehension has to iterate over the tuple at the Python level:

```
>>> dis.dis("[i for i in (1,2,3)]")
  1           0 LOAD_CONST               0 (<code object <listcomp> at 0x1075c0c90, file "<dis>", line 1>)
              2 LOAD_CONST               1 ('<listcomp>')
              4 MAKE_FUNCTION            0
              6 LOAD_CONST               5 ((1, 2, 3))
              8 GET_ITER
             10 CALL_FUNCTION            1
             12 RETURN_VALUE
```

`list` iterates over the tuple itself, and uses the C API to do it without going through (as much of) the Python data model.

```
>>> dis.dis("list((1,2,3))")
  1           0 LOAD_NAME                0 (list)
              2 LOAD_CONST               3 ((1, 2, 3))
              4 CALL_FUNCTION            1
              6 RETURN_VALUE
```

---

The Python-level iteration is more clearly seen in Python 2, which implements list comprehensions in a different fashion.

```
>>> def f():
...   return [i for i in (1,2,3)]
...
>>> dis.dis(f)
  2           0 BUILD_LIST               0
              3 LOAD_CONST               4 ((1, 2, 3))
              6 GET_ITER
        >>    7 FOR_ITER                12 (to 22)
             10 STORE_FAST               0 (i)
             13 LOAD_FAST                0 (i)
             16 LIST_APPEND              2
             19 JUMP_ABSOLUTE            7
        >>   22 RETURN_VALUE
```

As @blhsing points out, you can get disassemble the code object generated by the list comprehension in Python 3 to see the same thing.

```
>>> code = compile('[i for i in (1,2,3)]', '', 'eval')
>>> dis(code.co_consts[0])
  1           0 BUILD_LIST               0
              2 LOAD_FAST                0 (.0)
        >>    4 FOR_ITER                 8 (to 14)
              6 STORE_FAST               1 (i)
              8 LOAD_FAST                1 (i)
             10 LIST_APPEND              2
             12 JUMP_ABSOLUTE            4
        >>   14 RETURN_VALUE
```

Comment: Note that in Python 3 one would simply have to disassemble the code object stored in the `co_consts` list attribute of the parent code object as indexed to see the content of its byte codes. For example: https://repl.it/repls/SomberUniformAngles

Comment: @blhsing Oh, thanks. It hadn't occurred to me to try to disassemble the code object.

Comment: In python 3.7 I've noticed `dis` recurses into any nested code objects automatically, and accepts a depth parameter!

Comment: Oh! So it does.

Answer (score 1):

The `list` constructor is implemented purely in C and has therefore minimal overhead, while with a list comprehension the Python compiler has to build a temporary function, build an iterator, store the iterator's output as variable `i`, and load the variable `i` to append to a list, which are a lot more Python byte codes to execute than simply loading a tuple and calling the `list` constructor.